# How to display RabbitMQ messages dynamically in HTML (frontend)?

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq

I try to pass variables coming from RabbitMQ and display them in the frontend in my Django project. I am using HTML.
I can send the messages and receive them in backend and I can display them in console. But I try to display them in the frontend.
How can I do that?

**functions.py**

```
def send_message(text):
    credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('username', 'pass')
    parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters('ip',
                                           5672,
                                           '/',
                                           credentials)
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
    channel = connection.channel()

    channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

    channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='hello', body=text)
    print(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'")
    connection.close()

class my_class():
   def __init__(self, ...)
   send_message("Downloading...")
   self.download_all()
   ...
   def download_all(self, ...)
       ...
       var = ""
       arr_length = len(scans)
       for s in scans:
           i = 1
           var = "Progress = " + str(i) + "/" + str(arr_length)
           send_message(var)
           i += 1
```

**views.py**

```
def setup_wizard(request):
    functions.my_class(...)
    return render(request, 'setup_wizard.html', context)
```

**Note:** Celery don't work for us.

Comment: if you want to display it without reloading page then you will need `JavaScript` and `AJAX` ( ie. function `fetch(url,...)`) to get data from server. it will need also [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) to run it periodically.

Comment: your function has to `return` message so you could use `message = functions.my_class(...)`. And then you can use this message in `render()` to send it to template and display it. But this way you can display only one message. For more messages you would have to reload all page or use `JavaScript` to get only new message and replace it in HTML.